# Weird wiring question

Tags: solar

First, I have worked with electrical wiring quite a bit, but sometimes I come up with weird/possibly stupid questions. Here it goes. I have my solar panels wired in parallel because I had an old school charge controller. Now that I have an mppt, (out of sheer laziness) I was pondering what would happen if I merely reversed the positive and negative leads at the controller. Reason being, a series to parallel wiring scheme. It made me wonder if I could do that in reverse, ie, parallel to series wiring? Lol, again, im just trying to find any way around going on the roof and re wiring my panels. Whatever criticism I receive is understandably deserved. Thanks! Have at it!

Comment: From your statement you should understand how series and parallel circuits work, parallel add amps but not voltage, series add voltage but go to the minimum amp available on the smallest panel same as 1 weak cell can kill a battery, this is a case where a pro or some basic knowledge is mandatory, plus the code issues with open voltage but we won’t go there yet.

Comment: Parallel to serial and reversing the polarity are not the same thing.  This is "electronics 101" stuff you clearly don't have command of. I'd suggest doing some learning at Sparkfun, Adafruit etc.  You'll get up to speed quickly enough, and then after reviewing your panel specs and charge controller specs, it'll come together.

Comment: I'm not sure how switching wires at the controller will magically change the wiring on the roof from parallel to serial. Please [edit] to provide a schematic drawing of the existing layout and indicate what you're actually trying to achieve, because this sounds like an [XY Problem](https://xyproblem.info/) to me - "Here's my solution, will it work?" with us having no clue what the problem is...

Comment: Well I guess I was thinking that when you wire your panels in series yes you connect the negatives to the positives and so on and then to the controller when you wire in parallel you're wiring positive to positives, negatives to negatives. Series to parallel you got one - to one+ and the leftovers gat wired parallel. Would switching + & - when dealing with DC merely reverse polarity? Like I said, it was a thought. Parallel to series instead of series to parallel. FYI, this is off grid. Im not doing wacky experiments with city power, back feeding ect...

Comment: Lou you have to watch things like open voltage on the panels if you have 10 24v panels connected in series you could have 240v  the problem with series is 1 shaded panel and you loose the output. In parallel you only have 24v but setting up a series parallel 48v 5 times provides a better setup and more usable voltage input to most inverters (and it all comes down to what inverter type you have)

Comment: Thanks Ed, I'm playing with small stuff at this stage. 4 100 w panels with a 30 amp mppt and 2000 w inverter (standard rv set up). I was pondering the series to parallel to not over amp the charge controller when my question came to mind.